# Does an open()ed file get closed when nothing holds a reference to it?

Tags: python, file-io, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, contextmanager

I know that the safe and recommended way to open files is to use context managers:

```
with open("x") as fh:
    do_something_with(fh)
```

I frequently encounter situations where I don't want to do anything with the file handle returned by `open()` other than reading or writing a file completely and then closing it. Closing the file is automatically handled by the context manager. But what if I don't use one?

For example, is this

```
with open("x.pickle", "rb") as fh:
    foo = pickle.load(fh)
more_code()
```

more or less equivalent to this?

```
foo = pickle.load(open("x.pickle", "rb"))
more_code()
```

Assuming that pickle (or whatever else creates/consumes the file) doesn't somehow keep the file handle around, and lets it go out of scope, it should eventually be garbage collected and the file closed, right?

I tested this trivial example by inserting `sleep(100000)` before `more_code()` and then checking `lsof` to see if the file still showed up as opened. In this test, it did not. So, again with the assumption that whatever reads/writes the file lets the file handle go out of scope, is this a safe practice?

Comment: _it should eventually be garbage collected and the file closed, right_ For possibly wildly varying values of "eventually", sure.

Comment: That's fine by me. If I wanted to control every minute detail of memory management, I probably wouldn't be using Python for the task. I'm actually more interested in not accidentally leaving too many files opened unnecessarily (as seen by the file system / operating system). *Eventual* garbage collection is expected and not a problem.

Comment: "*Eventual garbage collection is expected and not a problem."* ... until you run out of file descriptors and `open` calls fail as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python implementation of [iobase](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e501122876f7e6abf979fdb756d7edd0d924ba1/Modules/_io/iobase.c#L316), you can see that part of garbage collecting (`finalize`) an IO object is calling its `close` method with the attribute `_finalizing` set to True.  This class is a superclass of `TextIOBase`.

Note, of course, that this is a low-level implementation detail. I doubt that the Python documentation requires this to happen.